# how to drop a table that belong to a schema user in sys using substitution Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, drop

I tried to drop a table tableA owned by schema tom in sys.

I was able to achieve that with the statement

```
drop table tom.tableA
```

Not sure how to use substitution. Not working with the following statements.

```
define schema='tom'
drop table &schema.tableA
```

Comment: Use two dots. drop atble &schema..tableA

Answer (score 0):

From the ["Using Substitution Variables" documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/using-substitution-variables-sqlplus.html#GUID-DD1BE849-0B66-4F99-83D0-F3B9F5A0D361):

> If you want to append a period immediately after a substitution variable name, then use two periods together. For example, if "myfile" is defined as "reports" then the command:
>
> ```sql
> SQL> spool &myfile..log
> ```
>
> is the same as:
>
> ```sql
> SQL> spool reports.log
> ```

In your case, you need two periods and also to remove the string literal quotes around the schema name:

```sql
DEFINE schema=tom
DROP TABLE &schema..tableA
```